# Not able to open VS Code from Terminal in my MacBook BigSur11.3.1

Tags: visual-studio-code

Good day community. I have installed VS Code in my MacBook Air M1 chip running on BigSur 11.3.1 but whenever I set the `code` command in PATH (using `Command+Shift+P`) it only appears to be working for current session and doesn't work if I restart VSCode. I have to set the `code` command in PATH again. Please help me in configuring `code` command permanently so that i can open VSCode from any directory whenever I want. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have got the solution. After installing VSCode in your Mac (which will be in download folder) move VS Studio Code.app file to Application Folder and then again install the `code` command in PATH from VSCode(using `Command+Shift+P`) and thats it.